# Compared grouped minimum of one column to a group of timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe (extract only for one value of id3):

```
id1 id2 id3     id4 id5 id6  status id7   max_snsr_ts               max_ts_fs    k
292 346 1041    656 578 5780    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/22/2020 23:30    48
292 346 1041    657 708 7080    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/22/2020 23:30    48
292 346 1041    658 579 5790    on  53  10/19/2020 23:59    10/22/2020 23:30    48
292 346 1041    657 708 5780    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/23/2020 23:30    96
292 346 1041    658 579 7080    on  53  10/19/2020 23:59    10/23/2020 23:30    96
292 346 1041    656 578 5790    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/23/2020 23:30    96
```

I am trying to group by id3, select the minimum of the max_ts column and then compare that with the max_ts_fs for every group of id3 and k. Based on the result I would like to add a boolean as a separate column.

I was trying to do as follows:

```
joined_h_raw_fs['new_col'] = np.where(joined_h_raw_fs.groupby(['id3'])['max_snsr_ts'].min().min() > joined_h_raw_fs.groupby(['id3', 'k'])['max_ts_fs'] , True, False)
```

Expecting to get:

```
id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 status  id7 max_snsr_ts max_ts_fs   k   new_col
292 346 1041    656 578 5780    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/22/2020 23:30    48  FALSE
292 346 1041    657 708 7080    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/22/2020 23:30    48  FALSE
292 346 1041    658 579 5790    on  53  10/19/2020 23:59    10/22/2020 23:30    48  FALSE
292 346 1041    657 708 5780    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/23/2020 23:30    96  FALSE
292 346 1041    658 579 7080    on  53  10/19/2020 23:59    10/23/2020 23:30    96  FALSE
292 346 1041    656 578 5790    on  53  10/21/2020 23:59    10/23/2020 23:30    96  FALSE
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

pandas/_libs/tslibs/c_timestamp.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.c_timestamp._Timestamp.__richcmp__()

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I am still not very good in pandas as I am transitioning from dplyr.

Could someone point what I am doing wrong?

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want compare original columns use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original filled by aggregated values, also `np.where` is here not necessary.

```
s1 = joined_h_raw_fs.groupby(['id3'])['max_snsr_ts'].transform('min')
s2 = joined_h_raw_fs.groupby(['id3', 'k'])['max_ts_fs'].transform('min') 
joined_h_raw_fs['new_col'] = s1 > s2
```